# React keyborad landscape

Tags: reactjs, input, keyboard, landscape

I've a problem with react.
I've one web app with some forms and inputs field.
When I click and use the input field with the keyboard from pc, smartphone or tablet on portrait mode it's all ok, but when I change the orientation of the device and click on one field the keyboard appears, but it cover all the view.
How can I solve this problem?

Example of my Search component form:

```
 <div className="vv-search-form-layout">
  <div className="d-flex flex-row search-form">
    <input
      type='text'
      name="search"
      value={searchValue}
      className="form-control search-text"
      onChange={changeSearch}
      onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
      ref={this.searchInput}
     />
   </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.vv-search-form-layout {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
 
  @media (min-width: $md) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.search-form {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 35rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Pretty hard to debug without a minimal, reproducible example ;-)

Comment: Have you right, I've add the code of my search component form